# How to attach class to an element after click event is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have menu with `ul` and `li` and deeper `ul` in it and so on in a sidebar. What i want is when i click any of the `a` tag to attach a class `open` to my sidebar after the redirected page is rendered.

```
$(".menu__link").click(function() {
   $(".randomclass").toggleClass("another-random-class"); 
});
```

The **menu__link** is the class of my anchor tags. The problem is that when i click them it does what i want before redirect and render the other page. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear...

Comment: If you want something on the new page to change, then the code to do it has to be done *on the new page*. If need be, you can redirect to that page with an anchor (or query string), like `mypage.html#test`. You'd then have code on the new page that checks for this anchor, and if it's there, make whatever changes you want.

Comment: but there is like 100+ pages. Code the same thing on every page?